# Issues with cross browser compatibility in the following code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing issues in the following code.
This code is working fine in firefox, but when I tried the same on chrome, internet explorer 8, opera it is not working.

Following is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('bodyUl').ready(function(){

        // checking if we are at the end of the window
        $(document).scroll(function(){
            if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                loadNewData();
            }
        });

        function loadNewData(){
            alert('loadingNewData');    
            for (var i=0; i<20; i++){
                $('ul').append($('<li>'+new Date().getTime()+'</li>'));
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Please let me know what are the changes that I need to do make in this code to run it in all the browsers.
Thanks.

Comment: Can we have an error message you're getting?

Comment: Chrome, at least, has a developer console that you could use to check for errors. See any errors in the console?

Comment: This ` $('bodyUl').ready(function(){` seems so wrong.

Comment: You are enough lucky this code works somewhere...

Comment: @roasted What's wrong with it?

Comment: I think the important fix is that `$(document).scroll(` should be for `window` instead, like adeneo's answer includes

Comment: @Ian you are correct! But $(document).scroll() is fired in chrome

Comment: I have given body tag an ID as bodyUL.

Comment: This is the error that I am getting. 

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 14:39:29 UTC


Message: Object expected
Line: 72
Char: 3
Code: 0

Comment: in console of chrome it is showing, Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @roasted it is not working at my end. can you please share your code.

Comment: " $ is not defined " usually means jquery is not loaded... For my code, i'd use the same as adeneo's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only an element matching the current document has a `ready()` method :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if  ( $(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) ) {
            loadNewData();
        }
    });

    function loadNewData(){
        for (var i=0; i<20; i++){
            var li = $('<li />', {text:new Date().getTime()});
            $('ul').append(li);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't matter though, you can pass anything as the selector and call `.ready()` on it. It doesn't work as expected (like "waiting for that element to be ready"), but it's no different than `$(document).ready`. That's why `$().ready` is technically an option

Comment: I got the answer why "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" was printing into console of chrome,

Actually I have loaded the jquery in the below format:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

i download jquery into my localhost than i had given the path of that jquery.

Comment: Yeah, including jQuery helps a lot!